# OpenLayers - Set center and zoom based on multiple polygons

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using openlayers 6.5 and I want to set the center of the map and to fit all polygons drawned.

Here is what I have:

```
/*** Set the map ***/
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: map_element,
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([
            '24.6859325',
            '45.9852429',
        ]),
        zoom: 6
    })
});

/*** Set counties polygon on the map ***/
for(var county_id in map_json_data)
{
    map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'] = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([map_json_data[county_id]['county_polygon_coordinates']])
    });
    
    map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'].getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    
    map.addLayer(
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [ map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'] ]
            })
        })
    );
}

/*** Here I want to set all polygons to be centered on the map and to fill the maximum zoom ***/
```

Some help based on code I have ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build up a combined extent as you add features and then fit the view to that

```
var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

/*** Set counties polygon on the map ***/
for(var county_id in map_json_data)
{
    map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'] = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([map_json_data[county_id]['county_polygon_coordinates']])
    });
    
    map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'].getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    ol.extent.extend(extent, map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'].getGeometry().getExtent());
    
    map.addLayer(
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [ map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'] ]
            })
        })
    );
}

map.getView().fit(extent);
```

It could be made simpler if you are able to have all your polygons in a single vector layer

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();
map.addLayer(
    new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    })
);

/*** Set counties polygon on the map ***/
for(var county_id in map_json_data)
{
    map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'] = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([map_json_data[county_id]['county_polygon_coordinates']])
    });
    
    map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon'].getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

    vectorSource.addFeature( map_json_data[county_id]['google_map_county_polygon']);
}

map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
```